# How to invoke a return value method with final class object as paremeter in Android ?

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm new in Android and I've been trying to create a method to invoke another method (with parameters and return a List in SignalR api) that run a method in asp.net web api but I could't.

Method that is not recognize Invoke is:

```
List<ChatUser> retorno = hubProxy.invoke<ArrayList<ChatUser>>("MapList",latitude, longitude);
```

Below is method of Signalr class imported:

```
public <E> SignalRFuture<E> invoke(final Class<E> resultClass, final String method, Object... args) { ... });
```

In asp.net the method I use and works is:

```
IEnumerable<ChatUser> retorno = await hubProxy.Invoke<IEnumerable<ChatUser>>("MapList", latitude, longitude);
```

Web api method target:

```
public IEnumerable<ChatUser> MapList(double latitude, double longitude) {
      var mapItens = from i in userList
               where (i.UserType == "O" && i.Latitude > 0 &&
                      ((latitude - i.Latitude) < 0.600 || (longitude - i.Longitude) < 0.600))
               select i;
      return mapItens;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong.  Also the method doesn't return a List (unless SignalRFuture implements List), try this:

```
SignalRFuture<ChatUser> retorno = hubProxy.invoke(ChatUser.class,"MapList",latitude, longitude);
```